# = vs : in argument of method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, arguments

I know
Optional parameters is :
The **definition** of a method can specify that its parameters are required or that they are optional when define a method

but in method call, what is difference between : and = in arguments

```
Display(name="test") 
Column(name: "id")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example you're assigning the string `"test"` to a variable in the calling scope that is named `name` (whether it be a local variable, parameter, field, etc.) and then, since the assignment operator expression resolves to the value assigned,  `"test"` will end up being passed as the first parameter of `Display` *without using a named parameter* (meaning that snippet would function identically if `Display` renamed its parameter to something other than `name`).  Note that this code will not compile if there isn't a valid variable of type `name` in scope.

The second method call only passes the string `"id"` to `Column` as a named argument, without performing any other operations.